# Как проверить модификаторы метода?

Tags: java, рефлексия

Как проверить, является ли метод синхронизированным, да, я знаю что есть Modifier.isSynhronized(method.getModifiers()), да вот только на обычную функцию почему-то это не работает, вот пример:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        Method k = test();
        boolean i = Modifier.isSynchronized(test().getModifiers());
        System.out.print(i);
    }

    public static synchronized Method test(){
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Для решения данной проблемы вы должны создать переменную класса Method (Method method = Main.class или имя_класса.getClass()), вызвать у этого всего метод getDeclaredMethod и передать в него строкой какой метод вы хотите посмотреть, пример:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        Method method = Main.class.getDeclaredMethod("test");
        System.out.print(Modifier.isSynchronized(method.getModifiers()));
    }

    public static synchronized void test(){
    }
}
```

Вывод : true;